# Audit Login/Logout Events using ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack, audit-logging

I am new to ServiceStack and would like to know how to capture login (successful and failed attempts) information in a table during authentication and wanted to ask whether any of you have done this sort of work before. I also read about a feature called RequestLogger (see [ServiceStack Request Logger](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-logger) and not sure which way to go at the moment. I also read about using filters to intercept calls. Any pointers would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to look at [Session or Auth Events](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#session-events) for executing custom logic for different Session/Auth events.

But there's no custom event for **Failed Attempts** which are different depending on which auth provider was used, e.g. OAuth providers redirect users adding a `#f=ErrorType` suffix to the url to indicate what failed. You can catch this redirect by assigning a custom filter to `FailedRedirectUrlFilter` e.g:

```
Plugins.Add(AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
    new IAuthProvider[]
        new FacebookAuthProvider(AppSettings) { 
            FailedRedirectUrlFilter = (authProvider, url) => {
                var log = LogManager.GetLogger(authProvider.GetType());
                log.Info("Failed OAuth login attempt, redirecting to: ", url);
                return url; 
            }
        }
    });
```

Which logs a message using the registered [Logging provider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Logging).

Whilst a failed Credentials Auth login will throw an `UnAuthorized` HTTP Error which you can handle with a custom [Global Response Filter](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Request-and-response-filters), e.g:

```
this.GlobalResponseFilters.Add((req, res, response) => {
    var error = response as HttpError;
    if (error != null && req.Dto.GetType() == typeof(Authenticate))
    {
        //...
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated!